# Cmd Variables with Reserved Character %

Tags: variables, cmd, set

I have a service account that I am trying to assign a variable to - I am unable to change the password.

Password is "password%6k"

I repeat the % character to escape

```
SET $9=password%%6k
REM $9

Cmd Output:
password%6k

call startmaxl.bat %$9%

-> In MAXL 
echo "$9";

MAXL Output:
passwordK
```

This is causing my MAXL batch to fail due to incorrect credentials - 
How do I pass the properly formatted password to the MAXL engine?

New Code:

```
SET "$9=password%%6k"
echo $9=%9%
CALL echo $9=%9%

Cmd Output:
echo $9=password%6k

MAXL:
shell echo "$9";
MAXL Output: password%6k
-- This is correct now
```

The batch then exits expectantly - 
I have to specify this full path to start MAXL

```
Batch File Currently: 
echo Beginning Test at %time% on %date% > D:\Logs\TEST_START.log
SET (parameters 1-8)
SET "$9=password%%6k"
echo $9=%9%
CALL echo $9=%9%

D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem1\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\startMaxl.bat test.msh %$1% %$2% %$3% %$4% %$5% %$6% %$7% %$8% %$9%

echo Ending Test at %time% on %date% > D:\Logs\TEST_END.log
```

I'm currently able to pass the correct password through, build a portion of an essbase cube, but the batch is exiting immediately after the MAXL logs out and skips the last TEST_END log.

Is there anyway to do a CALL instead? How would I go about setting this up

Comment: If `%%` not working try the escape character `^%`.

Comment: As you're working in the Command Prompt, _(this is not a batch file)_, `SET $9=password%%6k` should read `Set "$9=password%6k"`, `call startmaxl.bat %$9%` should read `Call "startmaxl.bat" "%$9%"` and inside `startmaxl.bat` `%~1` would represent the value originally set to the variable named `$9`. Within `startmaxl.bat` you should use `%~1` where or when necessary to remove the enclosing doublequotes, and `%1` where they're required, _as it was passed already doublequoted_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Each `CALL` does one substitution of the variables](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) (see the first 2 output lines from the following simple `.bat` script). You could apply [DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
rem setlocal script level 
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem percent sign escaped by doubling
SET "$9=password%%6k"

rem use the $9 variable                # %% => %
echo $9=%$9% (echo^)

rem CALL the $9 variable               # %6 => 6th line parameter
CALL echo $9=%$9% (CALL echo^)
echo ---

rem setlocal call level
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
echo --- call startmaxl !$9:%%=%%%%!
call :startmaxl !$9:%%=%%%%!
rem endlocal call level 
ENDLOCAL

rem endlocal script level 
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

rem the following procedure substitutes startmaxl.bat script
:startmaxl
echo in %~0 parameter=[%~1], variable=[%$9%]
goto :eof
```

Please note that I'm calling an internal subroutine (label `:startmaxl`) instead of an external batch script (`startmaxl.bat`) *without loss of generality or accuracy*. You can use `call startmaxl.bat !$9:%%=%%%%!` with the same result.

**Output**:

```
D:\bat\SO\59793838.bat a b c d e SixthParam g
```

> ```
> $9=password%6k (echo)
> $9=passwordSixthParamk (CALL echo)
> ---
> --- call startmaxl password%%6k
> in :startmaxl parameter=[password%6k], variable=[password%6k]
> ```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked! I used "$9=password%%6K" then echo $9=%9% (CALL echo^) then echo $9 to review. In the MAXL script for the 9th variable I wrote "%9%" and that fed into the MAXL engine appropriately